# Allowing user to edit template files

Tags: joomla-3.x

I want to specific users with group `Admin` be allowed to edit template **files**.
But anything I do they can only change styles settings.

What should I do?

(I wonder is it better to add an editor into style settings, which code will be ran in the `index.php` file.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested assigning the relevant permissions to a standard administrator and this will does not allow them to edit template files.

The reason being is because giving them access will allow them to give themselves super admin access.

The only way you will be able to allow standard administrators to edit template files, is by giving them the same permissions as a super user, which effectively makes them super users anyway.

So the choice is entirely up to you whether or not you want to assign them the same permissions, but this is not possible without doing so.